# Which c++ constructor style is better?

Tags: c++, constructor, styles

Are these classes identical?  If so then which style is better?  I prefer `binary_node2` as it is easier to read.

```
class binary_node1
{
    public:
        binary_node* left;
        binary_node* right;
        int value;
        binary_node1(int v):left(nullptr),right(nullptr),value(v)
        {
        }
};
class binary_node2
{
    public:
        binary_node* left=nullptr;
        binary_node* right=nullptr;
        int value;
        binary_node2(int v):value(v)
        {
        }
};
```

Comment: Prefer smart pointers; `std::unique_ptr` in this case.

Comment: I prefer `binary_node1` as it is easier to read.

Comment: The first : easier to read, consistent; flexible.

Comment: Prefer class member initializers. (the second one) Then you can't forget when you add/change a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in-class *default member initializers* as in `binary_node2` are quite useful when the constructor is overloaded, because the *default member initializer* (`nullptr` in this case) will be used to initialize the corresponding member (`left` and `right`) unless the member is explicitly initialized in the constructor's member initialization list (or the constructor delegates to another constructor) and therefore, it prevents you from having to specify the same initializers over and over.

For example:

```
class binary_node2
{
    public:
        binary_node* left=nullptr;
        binary_node* right=nullptr;
        int value;

        binary_node2(int v):value(v) {}
        binary_node2(): value(0) {} // left, right set to nullptr
};
```

If the wished value to initialize both the `left` and `right` members is `nullptr` for the default constructor, the code above will do.

Following the `binary_node1` approach (i.e.: **without** in-class default member initializers), it would have been:

```
class binary_node1
{
    public:
        binary_node* left;
        binary_node* right;
        int value;

        binary_node1(int v):left(nullptr),right(nullptr),value(v) {}
        binary_node1():left(nullptr),right(nullptr),value(0) {}
};
```

See the difference? In this case it avoids repetition, which can be error-prone.

Answer (score 5):

They are not for the same purpose.

The first one only provide init value for *one* specific constructor.

The second one will provide default value for *all* constructors if in that constructor the value of init is not particularly specified .